# Python using setters in mutually dependent class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code and the run-time error messages fully demonstrate the problem.

```
class A():
def __init__(self, x=None):
    self._x = x

@property
def x(self):
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, x):
    self._x = x


# Make two instances of class A
a = A()
b = A()
# Make each instance contain a reference to the other class instance by using
# a setter. Note that the value of the instance variable self._x is None at
# the time that the setter is called.
a.x(b)
b.x(a)
```

Run-time results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\Commands\Comands\test\commands\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    a.x(b)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I am running using Python 3.7.4.

Comment: Did you mean a.x = b ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.x(b)` will:

- get `a.x` -- which is `None` at that point
- call `None(b)` -- which is the source of the error as `NoneType` is not callable

To use the setter (which is a descriptor), you need to do attribute assignment:

```
a.x = b
b.x = a
```